# Imacros for facebook like

Tags: imacros

Just started to learn Imacros, recorder macros for Facebook to like page, but when i play macros it gives me this kind of error

> RuntimeError: element BUTTON specified by
>   TYPE:submit&&ID:u_0_1c&&DATA-OWNERID:u_0_1b&&DATA-PROFILEID:106053553060414&&CLASS:_42ft_4jy0PageLikeButton_4jy4_517h_9c6&&VALUE:1
>   was not found, line 6 (Error code: -921)

Answer (score 2):

You problem is,

> "submit&&ID:u_0_1c&&DATA-OWNERID:u_0_1b&&DATA-PROFILEID:106053553060414&&CLASS:_42ft_4jy0PageLikeButton_4jy4_517h_9c6&&VALUE:1 "

points to a spesific a specific button, I assume you want to click any like button from whatever page you are on you should choose a more general selector. On the record in imacros you can choose multiple methods of recording choose a different one.